# Pass time to a method in C#

Tags: c#, datetime, methods

I have 2 classes my `Program` class and my `GetDateAndTime` class. I'm getting the time in my `GetDateAndTime` class and I want to pass the time to my main method. I can get the time no problem from my `GetDateAndTime` but when passing the time back to my `program` class I get 00:00:00 instead of 18:00:00. I'm getting my time from my config file.

My code is as follows

Config file

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="StartTime" value="18:00:00" />
</appSettings>
```

**Program Class**

```
private static DateTime t;
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    DateTime day=DateTime.Now;
    GetDateAndTime.CheckDays(day, t);
}
```

**GetDateAndTime Class**

```
public static DateTime CheckDays(DateTime day, DateTime t)
{
    var startTimeString = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["StartTime"];
    t = DateTime.Parse(startTimeString);
    t.ToString("HH:mm:ss");
    Console.WriteLine(t.ToString("HH:mm:ss"));
    return day;
}
```

Comment: If you want your `day` variable in `Main` to be updated, you either need to assign it the output from `CheckDays` or change the `day` parameter of `CheckDays` to be `ref`. The former would be preferred.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the call

```
GetDateAndTime.CheckDays(day, t);
```

you are not using the return value. The type `DateTime` is a value type, which cannot be modified in-place, unless the `ref` keyword is used.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What do you suggest I do?

Comment: Assign the return value to a variable, like `day = GetDateAndTime.CheckDays(day, t)`. Alternatively, change the return type to `void` (to avoid confusion) and endow the parameter `day` with the `ref` keyword.

Comment: Well, you can't modify a `DateTime` even with `ref` because it's immutable. All "modifying" methods like [`Add`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.add(v=vs.110).aspx) actually return a new `DateTime`. If you use `ref` you needed to re-assign the new DateTime to the parameter.

Comment: Thank you very much. This sorted it for me I used `ref` :)

Answer (score 0):

> but when passing the time back to my program class

This statement is not represented in your code.  You never pass the time back to your program, so your program doesn't know about it.